# Does Ubuntu server 20.x have default firewall settings?

Tags: server, 20.04, administration

I am using Ubuntu server 20.04 on my server and today wanted to check what ports are open and found that neither `iptables` nor `ufw` are installed.

Is there some other firewall installed by default on Ubuntu server, or does Ubuntu just leave everything open by default?

Thanks

Comment: Modern versions of Ubuntu Server generally have `ufw` installed and enabled with some basic settings in place unless the tool was explicitly excluded during the installation process. Ubuntu Desktop does not have `ufw` enabled by default.

Comment: @matigo Thanks for your reply. I have what was installed from vps and I see that ufw is not installed nor iptables. Does that mean I have zero firewall protection?

Comment: I cannot answer your question if it's with a VPS. Some VPSes, such as Amazon, block everything via their firewalls. It's not until you explicitly elect to give the server a public IP or attach it to a load balancer that traffic from outside the network can reach the instance. You will need to confirm with your provider what sort of protections they offer out of the box.

Comment: as far as I have ever known, UFW is disabled by default on Ubuntu server also, and it has no firewall by default.

Comment: @Doug Smythies Thanks for you answer. Is there a way I can check? I have checked for iptables and ufw and neither are installed. Is there something else to look for?

Comment: @matigo My server is running on a public ip with not further protection than what ubuntu server offers by default.

Comment: you might still have nft, I don't know. Try [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588998/check-whether-iptables-or-nftables-are-in-use). I agree that if your server is public facing, it should have a firewall.

Comment: @Doug Smythies nothing is returning for nft either. By the way, I'm using a reverse nginx proxy. Does that count as a firewall?